# compact framework: Update of label in thread not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework

In a program for a mobile device (windows mobile), where I use compact framework 3.5,
I download a file and want to monitor the progress, by showing it in a Windows.Forms.Label.

Here my code:

**Start of my thread (in a button-click-event)**

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() => DownloadFile(serverName, downloadedFileName, this.lblDownloadPercentage));
Thread t = new Thread(ts);
t.Name = "download";
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

**My thread-method**

```
static void DownloadFile(string serverName, string downloadedFileName, Label statusLabel)
{
      HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverName);
      do
      {
            //Download and save the file ...
            SetPercentage(statusLabel, currentProgress);
      } while(...)
 }
```

**The method to update the label-text**

```
 private static void SetPercentage(Label targetLabel, string value)
 {
      if (targetLabel.InvokeRequired)
      {
           targetLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
           {
                targetLabel.Text = value;
           });
      }
      else
      {
           targetLabel.Text = value;
      }
 }
```

The download and saving part works fine, but when it comes to the targetLabel.Invoke-part (3rd code-snippet) the program stops doing anything. No crash, no error message, no exception. It just stops.

What is going wrong here?

Btw, if I leave the t.Join() away, the thread doesn't start at all... (Why that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am sure you get a `DeadLock` here.

main thread is waiting in `t.Join();` then when worker thread calls `targetLabel.Invoke` main thread can't invoke it since it is waiting in `Join` which is never going to happen. This situation is called [Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) in computer science.

Remove the `Join()` and it should work.

> Btw, if I leave the t.Join() away, the thread doesn't start at all... (Why that?)

Not sure what is that, that is not how it is supposed to be, Try to debug the application and figure it out. If not found provide us more info to get help.

Hope this helps